# setting up multiple buttons at once

Tags: android, button

So Im trying to make a calculator (first app) but Instead of having each button setup by itself, is there away to do them all at once?

this is how it's setup now:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (decimal == true) {
                String onScr = String.valueOf(firstTextView.getText());
                onScr = onScr + 1;
                firstTextView.setText(onScr);
                CurrentVal+= 0.1;
            }
            else {
                if (CurrentVal == 0) {
                    firstTextView.setText("1");
                    CurrentVal++;
                } else {
                    String onScr = String.valueOf(firstTextView.getText());
                    onScr = onScr + 1;
                    firstTextView.setText(onScr);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I managed to get it working, but want to condense the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can `implement View.OnClickListener` in your `Activity` (or `Fragment`) and then pass that as your `Listener` when setting up your `Buttons`.

This will allow you to condense your click handling code and clean up the Button assignment part too. Much neater code and easier to maintain.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        // since your Activity implements View.OnClickListener
        //   you can pass it as an argument here.
        button1.setOnClickListener(this)
        button2.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // get the clicked view's Id and act accordingly
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
                clickedButton1();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                clickedButton2();
                break;
            // if you didn't set up a 'case' for a received click, log it
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unhandled button press!");
                break;
        }
    }

    // if your code is moderately long you can
    //   move it outside of your onClick() too

    private void clickedButton1()
    {
        // do something
    }

    private void clickedButton2()
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button Btn1, Btn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    Btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    Btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            Log.i("myTag", "Button1 Clicked");
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Log.i("myTag", "Button2 Clicked");
            break;
}

}
```

Comment: You can't declare members outside the class scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do. It's not exactly what you asked for, but you can change it according to your needs. It works with number buttons. You have to write more onClickListeners for other buttons. Here, *resultString* is an EditText.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> calculatorButtonList;

calculatorButtonList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button0);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button1);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button2);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button3);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button4);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button5);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button6);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button7);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button8);
calculatorButtonList.add(R.id.button9);

for(int i=0; i<calculatorButtonList.size(); i++) {
  final String buttonText = ((Button) findViewById(calculatorButtonList.get(i))).getText().toString();
  ((Button) findViewById(calculatorButtonList.get(i))).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      resultString.setText(resultString.getText().append(buttonText));
      resultString.setSelection(pairingKey.getText().length());
    }
  });
}
```